# see "View in Browser" action directly for html email in Outlook 2010

Tags: html-email, outlook-2010

In outlook 2010 (Windows 7), for some html email, I can see the "View in Browser" action directly like below

[image]

While for some html emails, I can't see this directly, I have to select it from menu

Do you know which part of the html triggered this ?

Reason behind it is to make sure people using outlook 2010 have chance to see better email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line of HTML at the bottom of the document before the closing body tag.

```
 <span style="padding: 0px;"></span>
```

Comment: amazing, it just works, will be nice if you can add link to show why it works like this ;-)